# Macro to copy data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with a macro that I'm trying to create that will pull data into a Master workbook from a different workbook that is updated weekly.

The problem I'm having is that the file I receive weekly is always named differently (updated for the week ending) and 7 of the 8 tabs in the workbook are also named differently (one for each day of the week that applies in that week ending range).

If it was a static file name, the macro is a piece of cake and works perfectly. I've read a great deal on a number of forums about how you can set it the macro to look at an ACTIVE workbook, rather than a specifically named one, but I just can't seem to get that to work.

Below is my macro for the specifically name file; what do I need to do differently so that I can run it on the file I receive each week just by having it open and active?

```
Sub SecData()
'
' SecData Macro
' Macro to move security badge-in data from weekly file to Master Security Log workbook.  Will overwrite Sheet1
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Range("A2").Select
    Windows("Framingham counts for the week ending 06-02-18.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("05-27").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Master Security Logs.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A13").Select
    Windows("Framingham counts for the week ending 06-02-18.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("05-28").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Master Security Logs.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    Range("A32").Select
    Windows("Framingham counts for the week ending 06-02-18.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("05-29").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Master Security Logs.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D32").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    Range("A2154").Select
    Windows("Framingham counts for the week ending 06-02-18.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("05-30").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Master Security Logs.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D2154").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("A4378").Select
    Windows("Framingham counts for the week ending 06-02-18.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("05-31").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Master Security Logs.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D4378").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Range("A6638").Select
    Windows("Framingham counts for the week ending 06-02-18.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("06-01").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Master Security Logs.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D6638").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    Range("A8435").Select
    Windows("Framingham counts for the week ending 06-02-18.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("06-02").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Master Security Logs.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 7397
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2466
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not have the user chose the workbook and then choose the worksheet within that workbook, then you do not care about the names?  Then you can begin your macro processing on the selected worksheet.  I say this because I have a similar project where a user must specify 3 workbooks and worksheets in prompted order so that they can be "merged/processed".

Comment: That's new territory for me .. how would I have the user specify them?

Comment: Part 1 initiates a file selection dialogue, Part 2 is a little more tricky: usually a user form with a listbox (with worksheet names).  But here is another idea, are the worksheets in the selected workbook always in the right order? 7 workdays and then a summary worksheet (you said 8 worksheets).  Then you could ignore the names and use the worksheet position number (warning: this is not foolproof, if a user switches up the tab positions, the macro will no provide the desired results).

Comment: Yes, they are always in the same order.  Summary sheet, followed by the 7 days of the given week.

Comment: Wookies-Will-Code, I don't believe that having a listbox with the worksheet names is the most feasible option.  I'd end up with 365 as each tab is daily data.  The worksheet positioning idea seems like the better option.  Could you provide me any direction on how to do that?  Also, how do I get around the fact that the filename itself is different each week?

Comment: @LaceyLaDue I recommend reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). It solves many issues, makes your code much shorter (easier to maintain) a lot faster and more reliable/stable.

Answer (score 0):

@Lacey LaDue, I can't really make good sense of the copy and paste ranges but I know what you are doing, defining the range of the copy sheet, selected a cell in your master sheet and pasting it in.

365 tabs?  I thought you were doing this weekly?

You could always copy tab (worksheets) themselves but it looks like you are putting a weeks data on a single master sheet page.

Here is the frame work in one sub (macro) but I did not perform the copy and paste for each worksheet into your master worksheet / workbook, but this gets you close as it shows you how to get the file, open the file, and then walk through the worksheets 1 at a time and perform tasks on them.

I would need to know more about the copysheet and the master sheet to do the detail work. I hop this helps you out.  I am guessing your macro code is from the macro recorder because of all of the selects.

```
Option Explicit

'Sub to get the Current urFileName
Private Sub getFN()

    Dim Finfo As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Long
    Dim Title As String

    Dim CopyBook As Workbook    'Workbook to copy from
    Dim CopySheet As Worksheet  'Worksheet to copy from
    Dim FN As Variant           'File Name
    Dim wsNum As Double         'worksheet # as you move through the Copy Book
    Dim cwsLastRow As Long      'copy worksheet last row
    Dim mwsLastRow As Long      'master worksheet last row
    Dim masterWS As Worksheet   'thisworkbook, your master worksheet

    Set masterWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Security Logs")

    'Set up file filter
    Finfo = "Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*"
    'Set filter index to Excel Files by default in case more are added
    FilterIndex = 1
    ' set Caption for dialogue box
    Title = "Select the Current AP Reconcile Workbook"

    'get the Forecast Filename
    FN = Application.GetOpenFilename(Finfo, FilterIndex, Title)

    'Handle file Selection
    If FN = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbExclamation, "Not so fast"
    Else
        'Do your Macro tasks here
        'Supress Screen Updating but don't so this until you know your code runs well
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'Open the AP File
        Workbooks.Open (FN)
        'Hide the file so it is out of the way
        Set CopyBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For wsNum = 1 To CopyBook.Sheets.Count 'you stated there will be 8, this is safer
            'Do your work here, looks like you are copying certain ranges from wach sheet into ThisWorkbook
            CopySheet = CopyBook.Worksheets(wsNum) '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

            'Finds the lastRow in your Copysheet each time through
            cwsLastRow = CopySheet.Cells(CopySheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            'so you would have to keep tabs on what the lastRow of this sheet is too and always start at +1
            mwsLastRow = masterWS.Cells(masterWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            'Do some copy and pasting between copySheet and masterWS based on your ranges
            'It looks like you copy data from each ws into your single master book worksheet

            'Clear the clipboard before you go around again
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next wsNum
    End If

    'Close the workbook opened for the copy
    CopyBook.Close savechanges:=False 'Not needed now

    'Screen Updating Back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to copy the tabs from the selected workbook into your master workbook rather than specific data ranges, that is a different plan of attack, file selection is the same though.